# validate string with regex on android

Tags: java, android, regex

I want that my string didn't contain `*`,`;` and `$`. I use this code

```
private static boolean IsMatch(String s, String pattern) {
         try {
             Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
             Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
             return matcher.matches();
         } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           return false;
         }  
}



String regex ="[^*;$]";
System.out.println(IsMatch(url,regex));
```

But this method return always false.
Can any one tell me what's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `[^*;$]*` for your regex. It'll return true if your string doesn't contain any of `*`, `;` and `$`. I'm assuming you want your regex to match strings that *don't* contain any of those characters since you're already using `^` inside `[` and `]`.

Comment: @foufi: this returns true for me with your method: `System.out.println(IsMatch("http://example.com", "[^*;$]*"));`

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `[^\\*;\\$]*`. *  and $ are special characters in regex.

Edit: If you're using `Pattern` you should use this regex: `String regex = "^[^\\*;\\$]*$"`, since you want to match the whole string.

As an alternative you could just use `url.matches("[^\\*;\\$]*");` where you don't need the first ^ and last $, since that method tries to match the whole string anyways.

Comment: True, I took ^ as a character, not the negation. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out ^ and $, because they can occur anywhere in your string.

`String regex = "[\*,;\$]";`

Note the backslash escaping the $ symbol. Edit: and the * symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape some of the characters like this [\^*;\$]