# Android EditText check assistance

Tags: java, android

I have an editText field for which I want check that it meets with certain criteria, basically it has to contain 2ints and 3 strings, how can I check this before adding the element.

```
 EditText.getText().toString();
```

could I add a check that does comething like this

```
public boolean checkString(String StringPassed) {

   String s = StringPassed;
if(s.length == 5){
  boolean hasString = false;
  boolean hasInt = false;
  String letters = s.substring(0, 2);
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(letters);
  if (m.matches()) {
    hasString = true;
  }
  String numbers=s.substring(2,5);
  try {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
    String n = num + "";
    if (num > 0 && n.length() == 3)
        hasInt = true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  if (hasInt && hasString) {
   return true;
  }
 }else{
  return false;
 }
return false;
}
```

I then have a method which will say

```
public void addString() {

String StringPassed =  EditTextName.getString().toString();
checkString(String StringPassed);

if (StringPassed() == false) {
Display Toast;
}
else {
      add;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String s = edittext.gettext();
    if(s.length == 5){
      boolean hasString = false;
      boolean hasInt = false;
      String letters = s.substring(0, 2);
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(letters);
      if (m.matches()) {
        hasString = true;
      }
      String numbers=s.substring(2,5);
      try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
        String n = num + "";
        if (num > 0 && n.length() == 3)
            hasInt = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      if (hasInt && hasString) {
        //success
      }
     }else{
      // incorrect string
     }
```

Also you can add a `TextWatcher` on your `edittext` to listen for the text input change and call your method automatically

Comment: alot of examples here not sure which one to use, I only want to do the check if the string.length is ==5 otherwise it will incorrect anyways

Comment: i modified my answer for you specifications

Comment: Thanks for the help, but does this allow 1 int or 3 int or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: it parses the substring to check if the last tree characters are integers so if you have a string like this "ab123" it passes true and if you have a string like this "ab12a" it passes false

Comment: thaks for this does there need to be a , between a-z and A-Z? and i just say if say methodName() == false is another method?

Comment: no it doesn't, its just a REGEX expression. Also if it works don't forget to checkmark my answer :) Good luck with your project

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work, as I want it to do is check the details entered and in my add method it will pass the string to this method to check and return true if valid false if invalid

Comment: so if I understand correctly it returns false every time? even if the string is correct?

Comment: it just doesnt seem to do what I want it to as in it will still let me add even if the string is say aa or a123 or a1234, updated above to show how I am using it

Comment: can you just explain to me also as I was a little confussed myself.

Comment: yes the regular expression checks to see if the string contains letters between a to z or A to Z but I had to make the check explicitly ONLY letters. Right now if it contains a minimum of one letter it still passes true so that's the problem. We need to limit the scan only to letters.

Comment: but I thought it was checking substring 0,2 ie character 1 and 2 for letters a-z and A-Z anyways

Comment: it does but if it finds a single letter it returns true even if the second character is a number or a symbol, so that's what I need to change. I need to make the scan for letters ONLY

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any built-in solutions for this, but you could loop through the string and make a regular expression that would check the given character for being an integer?

Maybe something like:

```
Boolean isInteger = Pattern.matches("\d", text.toString()); ?
```

Comment: so I could simply place in the ("[a-z, A-Z]","[a-z, A-Z]","\d", "\d", "\d", text.toString());

Answer (score 0):

We can implement

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v , int keyCode , KeyEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == // Test whether a Number or Alphabet) {

                // Increase the tag here
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

But I think there must be some Implicit function for this I am still searching that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a good example of using a regex to verify that a string is in a certain format. Below is a code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646383/validate-string-with-regex-on-android) that works to verify that a string is [a-z] [a-z] [0-9] [0-9] [0,9].

```
package com.ruralogic.regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegexActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String regex ="[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]";
        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        if(IsMatch("123ab",regex)){
            text1.setText("true");
        }else{
            text1.setText("false");
        }
        if(IsMatch("ab123",regex)){
            text2.setText("true");
        }else{
            text2.setText("false");
        }
    }

    private static boolean IsMatch(String s, String pattern) {
        try {
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
            return matcher.matches();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```